# Why width property doesn't work on my table?

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

I have a code like this:

```css
main {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  float: right;
  height: auto;
}

div.container {
  width: 95%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

main div.container>table {
  width: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Nama event</th>
          <th>Kategori event</th>
          <th>Keterangan event</th>
          <th>Waktu event</th>
          <th>Lokasi event</th>
          <th>Cover</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>something</td>
          <td>something</td>
          <td>something</td>
          <td>something</td>
          <td>something</td>
          <td>something</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</main>
```

But the table width doesn't work. When I try the width over than 322px it works, but when I try width < 322px isn't work (I try 10px but the `table` isn't become smaller). And I try to width > 33% it's work < 33% it's not work too. Why?
(The main width is 80% is because there is `aside` with `width 20%` on the left)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is due to the behavior table where you cannot decrease its width less than the needed width for its content.

To be able to change this you need to set `table-layout` to fixed as by default it's auto and as you can read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp):

> Automatic table layout algorithm (this is default):
>
> The column width
>   is set by the **widest unbreakable content** in the cells Can be slow,
>   since it needs to read through all the content in the table, before
>   determining the final layout

and

> Fixed table layout algorithm:
>
> The horizontal layout only depends on
>   the **table's width** and the **width of the columns**, not the contents of
>   the cells Allows a browser to lay out the table faster than the
>   automatic table layout The browser can begin to display the table once
>   the first row has been received

```css
main {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  float: right;
  height: auto;
}

div.container {
  width: 95%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

main div.container>table {
  width: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Keterangan event</th>
          <th>Waktu event</th>
          <th>Lokasi event</th>
          <th>Lokasi event</th>
          <th>Cover</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>something</td>
          <td>something</td>
          <td>something</td>
          <td>something</td>
          <td>something</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    after adding table-layout:fixed;
    <table style="table-layout:fixed;">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Keterangan event</th>
          <th>Waktu event</th>
          <th>Lokasi event</th>
          <th>Lokasi event</th>
          <th>Cover</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>something</td>
          <td>something</td>
          <td>something</td>
          <td>something</td>
          <td>something</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

   
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you need?...you set Table->width : 10px..... i guess you meant td->width: 10px..

```css
.main {
 
  width: 100%;
  
 
}
div.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
div.container > table {
  width: 90%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Nama event</th>
          <th>Kategori event</th>
          <th>Keterangan event</th>
          <th>Waktu event</th>
          <th>Lokasi event</th>
          <th>Cover</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>something</td>
            <td>something</td>
            <td>something</td>
            <td>something</td>
            <td>something</td>
            <td>something</td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why you *guess* he meant td ? :) he used the word table a lot of time so am pretty sure he meant table

Comment: @TemaniAfif because that;s what cause the problem...what's the logic in setting the  width of the entire table to 10px?

Comment: he's not trying to set it to 10px, as you can read he's not able to change the width at all (10px is just an example) and this is due to nature of table. And it's logic to try to change width of elements even for small values

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But sorry, when I try your advice. The <td> width is still can't manual change less than the td width need.