# Table header doesn't follow table body dimensions when I fix table header and make body scrollable

Tags: html, css

So, basically following image easily describes my issue. What I need is thead headers being aligned with tbody cells while keeping the functionality of fixed header with scroll bar for tbody. Can anyone help me with that please?

Right now, if you inspect it on the Codepen, the thead have same width as tbody but somehow the size of cells in the thead is different one compared to tbody.

https://codepen.io/seva98/pen/qBZZrKG

```css
.container {
  width: 600px
}

table {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-areas: "head-fixed" "body-scrollable";
  width: calc(100%);
}

th,
td {
  width: 33%;
  padding: 2px 16px;
}

thead {
  grid-area: head-fixed;
}

tbody {
  grid-area: body-scrollable;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 200px;
}


/* width */

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}


/* Track */

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}


/* Handle */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #888;
}


/* Handle on hover */

 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #555;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Heading 1</th>
        <th>Heading 2</th>
        <th>Heading 3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>Short</td>
        <td>Loooooooooong text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Short</td>
        <td>Loooooooooong text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Short</td>
        <td>Loooooooooong text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Short</td>
        <td>Loooooooooong text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Short</td>
        <td>Loooooooooong text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>Short</td>
        <td>Loooooooooong text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>Short</td>
        <td>Loooooooooong text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>Short</td>
        <td>Loooooooooong text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>Short</td>
        <td>Loooooooooong text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>Short</td>
        <td>Loooooooooong text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>Short</td>
        <td>Loooooooooong text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>Short</td>
        <td>Loooooooooong text</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: if use this style for table  `table {display: table; text-align: left;}` will solve your problem

Comment: @Ramineghbalian it won't because you will lose fixed header + scrolling functionality, just try it in the codepen link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a minimum width for td,th and also align its to left

Add this to `td,th`

```
  th,td {
       text-align: left;
       min-width:100px;
  }
```

instead of using

```
th,td {
    width: 33%;
}
```

Try this code pen :  https://codepen.io/Rayeesac/pen/mdPPwgg

For more information try this: [Why width property doesn't work on my table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48049965/why-width-property-doesnt-work-on-my-table)